# On-demand in-memory bundling of Javascript files at runtime

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, microservices, backend

I'm wondering whether there is a nice way to continuously bundle complex javascript files in a single, customized, JS file that is then directly served to clients, sort of a *"smart" CDN*.

My use case is really simple: serve JS files to different web applications from a microservice, like RUM scripts (or also Google AdSense scripts, or anything else that works by importing a JS file from a service in your web application).
Problem is, at every request the JS file will be **different**, based on several parameters (for example, IP address of the request, query params in the URI, back-end configuration, and so on).

Solution can be trivial, for example I could manually bundle JS files by concatenating strings, and then serve the resulting file, with minimal logic or with the help of a standard template engine that handles placeholders/pre-processing within the source JS files.
I was wondering if there is a better way to do this, like using JS bundlers as *Webpack* or *Parcel.js*.
My experience in using JS bundlers is limited to their standard usage, so that use them in the build process (or at application startup), and make them write to disk the compiled JS file.

Is there anything better to use, or a best practice to suggest for my use case?
Programming language makes no difference, I added the node.js tag because ideally the backend would be developed using Express.js, but also Java or other compiled languages would be ok.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Sure, that's definitely possible.

- Esbuild (a new, fast bundler) has a well-documented Node.js API: https://esbuild.github.io/api/#js-specific-details

The two other bundlers you mention are similarly available:

- Webpack has a well-documented Node.js API: https://webpack.js.org/api/node/
- Parcel has a well-documented Node.js API: https://parceljs.org/api.html

Then it's just (always "just" ;-) ) a matter of hooking those up to the web framework of your choice and going to town.

I'd recommend thinking about caching in advance, though – even if e.g. Esbuild and Parcel are pretty fast, not doing work is always faster than doing work.